# Unable to resolve target 'Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications:X10:4'

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting a strange error while importing an android project to eclipse.
**Unable to resolve target 'Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications:X10:4'**. Tried with cleaning the project but then my resource file missing and i have tried to fix the project no use the same error. I am thinking this is am Android target problem.Any one get this error before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have installed the target required by the project.

Go to Project Properties -> Android and you will see a table with the installed targets. Check one of them, apply the changes and then clean the project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 and thank you. I think we are changing the  target required by the project.If yes can we change the lower version to higher version by the same way?